# Use dataparallel but only one GPU is used

Tags: deep-learning, segment, dataparallel

```
from segment_anything import sam_model_registry, SamPredictor
import os
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import argparse
import os
from torch import optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from DataLoader import TrainingDataset, stack_dict_batched
from utils import FocalDiceloss_IoULoss, get_logger, generate_point, setting_prompt_none
from metrics import SegMetrics
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import datetime
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch.utils.data.distributed import DistributedSampler
from torch.cuda.amp import GradScaler, autocast
import time
import random
from segment_anything.modeling import Sam, PromptEncoder, MaskDecoder,TwoWayTransformer
from efficientvit.models.efficientvit.efficientvim import image_encoder_efficientvim
from segment_any.modeling.image_encoder_vim import ImageEncoderViM

def setup_ddp(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12345'
    dist.init_process_group(backend='nccl', rank=rank, world_size=world_size)

def cleanup_ddp():
    dist.destroy_process_group()

def _build_mamba_sam(
    checkpoint=None,
):
    prompt_embed_dim = 256
    image_size = 256
    vit_patch_size = 16
    image_embedding_size = image_size // vit_patch_size
    sam = Sam(
        image_encoder=ImageEncoderViM(img_size=image_size),

        prompt_encoder=PromptEncoder(
            embed_dim=prompt_embed_dim,
            image_embedding_size=(image_embedding_size, image_embedding_size),
            input_image_size=(image_size, image_size),
            mask_in_chans=16,
        ),
        mask_decoder=MaskDecoder(
            num_multimask_outputs=3,
            transformer=TwoWayTransformer(
                depth=2,
                embedding_dim=prompt_embed_dim,
                mlp_dim=2048,
                num_heads=8,
            ),
            transformer_dim=prompt_embed_dim,
            iou_head_depth=3,
            iou_head_hidden_dim=256,
        ),
        pixel_mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
        pixel_std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
    )
    sam.eval()
    if checkpoint is not None:
        with open(checkpoint, "rb") as f:
            state_dict = torch.load(f)
        sam.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    return sam

def _build_efiicientvim_sam(
    checkpoint=None,
):
    prompt_embed_dim = 256
    image_size = 256
    vit_patch_size = 16
    image_embedding_size = image_size // vit_patch_size
    sam = Sam(
        image_encoder=image_encoder_efficientvim,

        prompt_encoder=PromptEncoder(
            embed_dim=prompt_embed_dim,
            image_embedding_size=(image_embedding_size, image_embedding_size),
            input_image_size=(image_size, image_size),
            mask_in_chans=16,
        ),
        mask_decoder=MaskDecoder(
            num_multimask_outputs=3,
            transformer=TwoWayTransformer(
                depth=2,
                embedding_dim=prompt_embed_dim,
                mlp_dim=2048,
                num_heads=8,
            ),
            transformer_dim=prompt_embed_dim,
            iou_head_depth=3,
            iou_head_hidden_dim=256,
        ),
        pixel_mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
        pixel_std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
    )
    sam.eval()
    if checkpoint is not None:
        with open(checkpoint, "rb") as f:
            state_dict = torch.load(f)
        sam.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    return sam

efficientvim_sam = _build_efiicientvim_sam()

def parse_args():   
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--work_dir", type=str, default="workdir", help="work dir")
    parser.add_argument("--run_name", type=str, default="mamba-sam-med2d", help="run model name")
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=3, help="number of epochs")
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=60, help="train batch size")
    parser.add_argument("--image_size", type=int, default=256, help="image_size")
    parser.add_argument("--mask_num", type=int, default=5, help="get mask number")
    parser.add_argument("--data_path", type=str, default="/mnt/dataset/SAMed2Dv1", help="train data path") 
    parser.add_argument("--metrics", nargs='+', default=['iou', 'dice'], help="metrics")
    parser.add_argument('--device', type=str, default='cuda')
    parser.add_argument("--lr", type=float, default=1e-4, help="learning rate")
    parser.add_argument("--resume", type=str, default=None, help="load resume")
    parser.add_argument("--sam_checkpoint", type=str, default=None, help="sam checkpoint")
    parser.add_argument("--iter_point", type=int, default=5, help="point iterations")
    parser.add_argument('--lr_scheduler', type=str, default=None, help='lr scheduler')
    parser.add_argument("--point_list", type=list, default=[1, 3, 5, 9], help="point_list")
    parser.add_argument("--multimask", type=bool, default=True, help="ouput multimask")
    parser.add_argument("--used_amp", type=bool, default=True, help="use amp")


    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.resume is not None:
        args.sam_checkpoint = None
    return args


def to_device(batch_input, device):
    device_input = {}
    for key, value in batch_input.items():
        if value is not None:
            if key=='image' or key=='label':
                device_input[key] = value.float().to(device)
            elif type(value) is list or type(value) is torch.Size:
                 device_input[key] = value
            else:
                device_input[key] = value.to(device)
        else:
            device_input[key] = value
    return device_input


def prompt_and_decoder(args, batched_input, model, image_embeddings, decoder_iter = False):
    if  batched_input["point_coords"] is not None:
        points = (batched_input["point_coords"], batched_input["point_labels"])
    else:
        points = None

    if decoder_iter:
        with torch.no_grad():
            sparse_embeddings, dense_embeddings = model.module.prompt_encoder(
                points=points,
                boxes=batched_input.get("boxes", None),
                masks=batched_input.get("mask_inputs", None),
            )
    
    else:
        sparse_embeddings, dense_embeddings = model.module.prompt_encoder(
            points=points,
            boxes=batched_input.get("boxes", None),
            masks=batched_input.get("mask_inputs", None),
        )

    low_res_masks, iou_predictions = model.module.mask_decoder(
        image_embeddings = image_embeddings.to(dtype=torch.float16 if args.used_amp else torch.float32),

        image_pe = model.module.prompt_encoder.get_dense_pe(),
        sparse_prompt_embeddings=sparse_embeddings,
        dense_prompt_embeddings=dense_embeddings,
        multimask_output=args.multimask,
    )

    if args.multimask:
        max_values, max_indexs = torch.max(iou_predictions, dim=1)
        max_values = max_values.unsqueeze(1)
        iou_predictions = max_values
        low_res = []
        for i, idx in enumerate(max_indexs):
            low_res.append(low_res_masks[i:i+1, idx])
        low_res_masks = torch.stack(low_res, 0)

    masks = F.interpolate(low_res_masks,(args.image_size, args.image_size), mode="bilinear", align_corners=False,)
    return masks, low_res_masks, iou_predictions

def train_one_epoch(args, model, optimizer, train_loader, epoch, criterion, scaler):
    train_loader = tqdm(train_loader)
    train_losses = []
    train_iter_metrics = [0] * len(args.metrics)

    last_save_time = time.time()
    for batch, batched_input in enumerate(train_loader):
        try:
            batched_input = stack_dict_batched(batched_input)
            batched_input = to_device(batched_input, args.device)
            
            if random.random() > 0.5:
                batched_input["point_coords"] = None
                flag = "boxes"
            else:
                batched_input["boxes"] = None
                flag = "point"

            for _, value in model.module.image_encoder.named_parameters():
                value.requires_grad = True

            
            with autocast(enabled=args.used_amp):
                labels = batched_input["label"]
                image_embeddings = model.module.image_encoder(batched_input["image"])

                batch, _, _, _ = image_embeddings.shape
                image_embeddings_repeat = []
                for i in range(batch):
                    image_embed = image_embeddings[i]
                    image_embed = image_embed.repeat(args.mask_num, 1, 1, 1)
                    image_embeddings_repeat.append(image_embed)
                image_embeddings = torch.cat(image_embeddings_repeat, dim=0)

                masks, low_res_masks, iou_predictions = prompt_and_decoder(args, batched_input, model, image_embeddings, decoder_iter=False)
                loss = criterion(masks, labels, iou_predictions)


            scaler.scale(loss).backward(retain_graph=False)

            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            if int(batch+1) % 50 == 0:
                print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1}, Batch: {batch+1}, first {flag} prompt: {SegMetrics(masks, labels, args.metrics)}')

            point_num = random.choice(args.point_list)
            batched_input = generate_point(masks, labels, low_res_masks, batched_input, point_num)
            batched_input = to_device(batched_input, args.device)
        
            image_embeddings = image_embeddings.detach().clone()
            for n, value in model.named_parameters():
                if "image_encoder" in n:
                    value.requires_grad = False
                else:
                    value.requires_grad = True

            init_mask_num = np.random.randint(1, args.iter_point - 1)
            for iter in range(args.iter_point):
                if iter == init_mask_num or iter == args.iter_point - 1:
                    batched_input = setting_prompt_none(batched_input)

                with autocast(enabled=args.used_amp):
                    masks, low_res_masks, iou_predictions = prompt_and_decoder(args, batched_input, model, image_embeddings, decoder_iter=True)
                    loss = criterion(masks, labels, iou_predictions)
                scaler.scale(loss).backward(retain_graph=True)

                scaler.step(optimizer)
                scaler.update()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                
                if iter != args.iter_point - 1:
                    point_num = random.choice(args.point_list)
                    batched_input = generate_point(masks, labels, low_res_masks, batched_input, point_num)
                    batched_input = to_device(batched_input, args.device)
            
                if int(batch+1) % 50 == 0:
                    if iter == init_mask_num or iter == args.iter_point - 1:
                        print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1}, Batch: {batch+1}, mask prompt: {SegMetrics(masks, labels, args.metrics)}')
                    else:
                        print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1}, Batch: {batch+1}, point {point_num} prompt: { SegMetrics(masks, labels, args.metrics)}')

            if int(batch+1) % 200 == 0:
                print(f"epoch:{epoch+1}, iteration:{batch+1}, loss:{loss.item()}")
                save_path = os.path.join(f"{args.work_dir}/models", args.run_name, f"epoch{epoch+1}_batch{batch+1}_sam.pth")
                state = {'model': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
                torch.save(state, save_path)
            
            current_time = time.time()

            if current_time - last_save_time >= 10800:  
                hours_passed = (current_time - last_save_time) // 3600  
                formatted_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_time).strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')  
                print(f"Saving model at epoch {epoch+1}, batch {batch+1}, time {formatted_time} due to time limit.")
                
                save_filename = f"epoch{epoch+1}_batch{batch+1}_time{formatted_time}.pth"
                save_path = os.path.join(args.work_dir, "models", args.run_name, save_filename)
                state = {'model': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
                torch.save(state, save_path)
                
                last_save_time = current_time  
                
            train_losses.append(loss.item())

            gpu_info = {}
            gpu_info['gpu_name'] = args.device 
            train_loader.set_postfix(train_loss=loss.item(), gpu_info=gpu_info)

            train_batch_metrics = SegMetrics(masks, labels, args.metrics)
            train_iter_metrics = [train_iter_metrics[i] + train_batch_metrics[i] for i in range(len(args.metrics))]
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Skipping batch {batch} due to an exception: {e}")
            continue

    return train_losses, train_iter_metrics


def main(args):

    model = nn.DataParallel(_build_mamba_sam(args.sam_checkpoint)).to(args.device)
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():

        print(f"{name}: {param.device}")
    # if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    #     print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
    #     model = nn.DataParallel(model)

    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)
    criterion = FocalDiceloss_IoULoss()

    if args.lr_scheduler:
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[5, 10], gamma = 0.5)
        print('*******Use MultiStepLR')

    if args.resume is not None:
        checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume)  
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])  
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])  
        print(f"Loaded weights and optimizer state from {args.resume}")

    if args.used_amp:
        print("Use mixed precision")
    else:
        print('*******Do not use mixed precision')

    train_dataset = TrainingDataset(args.data_path, image_size=args.image_size, mode='train', point_num=1, mask_num=args.mask_num, requires_name=False)

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=40)

    print('*******Train data:', len(train_dataset))


    loggers = get_logger(os.path.join(args.work_dir, "logs", f"{args.run_name}_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M.log')}"))

    best_loss = 1e10
    l = len(train_loader)

    for epoch in range(0, args.epochs):
        scaler = GradScaler()
        model.train()
        train_metrics = {}
        start = time.time()
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(f"{args.work_dir}/models", args.run_name), exist_ok=True)
        train_losses, train_iter_metrics = train_one_epoch(args, model, optimizer, train_loader, epoch, criterion,scaler)

        if args.lr_scheduler is not None:
            scheduler.step()

        train_iter_metrics = [metric / l for metric in train_iter_metrics]
        train_metrics = {args.metrics[i]: '{:.4f}'.format(train_iter_metrics[i]) for i in range(len(train_iter_metrics))}

        average_loss = np.mean(train_losses)
        lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0] if args.lr_scheduler is not None else args.lr
        loggers.info(f"epoch: {epoch + 1}, lr: {lr}, Train loss: {average_loss:.4f}, metrics: {train_metrics}")

        if average_loss < best_loss:
            best_loss = average_loss
            save_path = os.path.join(args.work_dir, "models", args.run_name, f"epoch{epoch+1}_sam.pth")
            state = {'model': model.float().state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
            torch.save(state, save_path)

        end = time.time()
        print("Run epoch time: %.2fs" % (end - start))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    main(args)
```

I'm training on a Docker container on a remote Linux server equipped with six GPUs, and all the environments have been set up correctly. I'm using DataParallel to wrap my model. When I run my code, the training proceeds smoothly, but when I check with nvidia-smi, I find that only one GPU is being utilized for training. I'm curious to know why this is happening.

I've verified that all GPUs are available on my server, and I have checked for any version-related issues, finding nothing abnormal. What puzzles me most is that the code runs but only utilizes one GPU. I also noticed that with the setting parser.add_argument('--device', type=str, default='cuda'), training occurs on cuda:0. However, if I change this to default='cuda:1', then training moves to cuda:1.

This behavior indicates that the script is capable of running on a specified GPU, but it doesn't automatically distribute the workload across all available GPUs, despite my server having six of them. I am looking for a way to effectively utilize all GPUs for training to improve performance and efficiency.